# Proving that rotations of the angular momentum eigenstates are corresponding eigenstates

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, angular-momentum, rotation, quantum-states

If I apply a rotation operator about an arbitrary axis to a typical $\mathbf{J},J_z$ angular momentum eigenstate $|j,m \rangle$ then my sense from the development in Ballentine is that I also obtain an eigenstate (of the same $j,m$?) for the angular momentum along this axis. I can't seem to mathematize this, as a statement like
$$(\mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}})e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar}|j,m \rangle = m\hbar e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar}|j,m \rangle$$
has one free parameter ($\theta$) and is therefore surely wrong.

Can someone set me on the right track? How do I obtain angular momentum eigenstates about a different axis by applying a rotation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, your statement is wrong, but you almost have the right idea. Consider
$$ J_z|j,m \rangle = m\hbar  |j,m \rangle~~~\leadsto \\
\left (e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar} J_z e^{i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar}\right ) \left( e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar} |j,m \rangle \right ) = m\hbar \left (e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar}|j,m \rangle\right ),$$
which means you already have the eigenstates of the rotated generator,
$$J_{z'}\equiv  e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar} J_z  e^{i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar} ,$$
namely
$$J_{z'} \left( e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar} |j,m \rangle \right ) = m\hbar \left (e^{-i \mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}} \theta /\hbar}|j,m \rangle\right ).
$$

In particular, you might take $\theta=\pi/2$ around $\hat x$, so $z'=y$, and marvel... For example, in the doublet representation where these finite rotations are explicitly computable,
$$
\exp (-i\pi \sigma_x /4) ~~\sigma_z ~\exp (i\pi \sigma_x /4)\\ = (\cos\pi/4 -i\sigma_x \sin\pi/4)\sigma_z (\cos\pi/4 +i\sigma_x \sin\pi/4)\\ =\sigma_y.
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am confused though. Does not your $J_{z'}$ equal my $\mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}$?

Comment: Not if you rotate z around the n axis! Think of rotating z around the x axis by a right angle: you get y, not x…..

Comment: Ah, so you are saying in that case I gave that $\mathbf{J} \cdot \hat{\mathbf{n}}= J_x \neq J_y$, where the RHS is what I would get if I used the transformation law you gave?

Comment: Yes. I fleshed out the example.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Hi, just following up here again as I prove something Ballentine states in the text. As part of my proof, I am using the result you've stated above to essentially say something like the following. "Let $\hat{\mathbf{n}}$ be any direction, and suppose you want to obtain the joint eigenbasis of $J^2, J_{\hat{\mathbf{n}}}$. Then there exists some $\hat{\mathbf{n}}'$ and some $\theta$ such that $R_{\hat{\mathbf{n}}'}(\theta)|j,m \rangle$ is an element of that $J^2, J_{\hat{\mathbf{n}}}$ with the eigenvalues $j$ and $m$". Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it is; you got it.

Comment: Thank you! I am taking the existence (and presumably uniqueness, up to $2 \pi$ for $\theta$ of said $\hat{\mathbf{n}}'$ and $\theta$ on faith. Is it involved to think/ask about the proof of said statement? I imagine there's some group theoretic statement to be made.

Comment: (To be clear, I'll ask another question entirely if indeed it's not too involved.)

Comment: It’s evident geometrically…. Must be related to Euler’s [theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem)…

Comment: Got it, thank you (again)!